# How to convert an Ajax action link to java script?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, bootbox

Currently I have an action link which works as intended but I am trying to change it so that the ajax call happens after a screen shows up asking if they want to save, continue or cancel.

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "BrandCategoryModal", "BrandCategory", new { catId = brandCategory.SelectedCategory.CategoryId, brId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DisplayModal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", OnBegin = "CheckForChanges(" + brandCategory.SelectedCategory.CategoryId + "," + Model.Id + ")" })
```

Currently I am using bootbox to show this screen but the call is being made before an option is selected.

```
bootbox.prompt({
                title: "Select One:",
                inputType: 'checkbox',
                inputOptions: [
                    {
                        text: 'Save',
                        value: '1',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Don\'t Save',
                        value: '2',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        value: '3',
                    }
                ],
                callback: function (result) {
                    choice = result;
                    console.log(result);
                    if (choice[0] === "2") //Need to submit form
                    {
                        //$.ajax({
                        //   url: 'BrandCategory/BrandCategoryModal',
                        //   type: 'GET',
                        //    data: {
                        //        catId: cId,
                        //        brId : bId
                        //    }
                        //})
                        showModal('#DisplayModal')
                    }
                    else if (choice === "1") //Need to submit form
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (choice === "0") //Not set or cancelled
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you mean the ajax call in the callback function? Because I can't seem te reproduce the problem you're having

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, The ajax call in callback function is my new attempt at recreating the ajax actionlink within javascript

Comment: What call do you want to make when a user selects an option and clicks 'OK'?

Comment: when the user selects "Don't Save" it should continue with the actionlink which brings back a partial view that is to be displayed in a modal. if they select save then the actionlink is cancelled and another ajax call to the controller is made to save the current data on the form and if Cancel is selected then the ajax call is cancelled

Comment: This is already working for me see: https://jsfiddle.net/pbytxjx4/

Comment: The checkbox works but the ajax call is happening before the checkbox is shown where as I want the ajax call to only happen if the user selects don't save and to cancel if one of the other options is selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160608/discussion-between-rick-jelier-and-jack-tyler).

Comment: You're not really showing enough for anything other than a wild guess, but Bootstrap (and therefore Bootbox) modals are asynchronous functions - they can't block the "thread" like a native prompt. That means you need to cancel any click events or form submissions if that code needs to not execute until the modal is dismissed. This has been covered in the docs and in similar questions on Stack Overflow.